# Can't create a sql database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a application to manage sql databases, and i have a problem creating the database on my partition (C:) in any folder, but if i create it in partition (D:) for example it works. I am looking for a solution to this, maybe are the permissions for the sql user but i don't know how to change or add them. I am using the 'sa' user...

I am using Microsoft SQL

Comment: What have you tried and what errors do you get; and as BoltClock says, which *type* of database are you trying to create?

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. It's where i create the database (mdf file) that gives me an error, if i create it in my system partition (C:) in any folder it gives me the error, if i choose other partition it works fine.

Comment: @user595291: what have you tried and how does it fail? Post the code you are using.

Comment: My application asks where to place the databse and the name of it, then executes the sqlcommand to create it, it's where i got an error. It's similar to this project: "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/CreateDB.aspx", but do much more with the database, and i am using the same method in that project to create the database.

Comment: My application gives me the following exception:

CREATE FILE encountered operating system error 5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105) while attempting to open or create the physical file 'C:\abcde.mdf'.
CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errors.

Comment: On many server system, a "normal" user account isn't allowed to write into the C:\ root drive. What OS are you working on??

Comment: I am using Windows 7. But i am the Administrator in OS, and i am using the 'SA' account of Microsoft SQL, then supposedly i can save my database file wherever i want... But i have something wrong probably with my Microsof SQL, and i don't know what it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

where in the process does it error? when it goes to save the .mdf file? or when you try to run a query? It could be a Windows permission issue, do you have write access to where you are trying to put the file? Right click the folder and choose properties, then go to the security tab, if your user-name is in the list click it and make sure you have write access.

Comment: If you have AOL instant messenger my SN is: DJ29Joesph

Comment: I am not referring to the partition where i have installe the Microsof SQL, but where i create my database (mdf) file, i can create it in wherever i want, except in my system partition. I already have exposed the error that my app gives.

Comment: see if it saves in your "My Documents" or Documents (vista and win 7) folder, if it does its a windows permission issue (you shouldn't be saving in the root of system drive anyway)

Comment: I already tried saving in my Desktop, and in My Documments. I am using root system drive for example. But i am an Administrator in my OS, how can it be windows permissions?

Comment: if that's the case, it can't be. It could be a bad setup of the server, although I doubt it since it saves on another partition. What OS (operating system) are you using?

Comment: Maybe it is a bad setup with my Microsoft SQL software. But i already tried save the database file in partition (D:) for example and it works fine. I am using Windows 7.

Comment: I suggest removing the install of Microsoft SQL and reinstalling. It seems like a bad install with permissions.

Comment: The problem is solved!

It really was a bad installation. And it was one of two things:

1 - The anti-virus was deleting or blocking some of the files to be written on disk from the SQL setup, because in the other installation the setup shown 2 warnings.

2 - Or it was the accounts, because when i had to configure the accounts of services in the SQL, i choose them randomly, now i have done it carefully, and maybe it works because of that.

Thanks